# How can I align an pyqtgraph IsocurveItem instance to empty plot axes (rather than an ImageItem)?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

## The Problem

The pyqtgraph documentation for [IsocurveItem](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/isocurveitem.html) helpfully suggests that contours drawn with this class can be aligned to an `ImageItem` instance by `isocurve.setParentItem(image)`. But if I don't want to show image data, how can I scale the contour output to properly align with the axes given X,Y data?

## Example setup

Using this code sample to draw:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

# Setup
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

win = pg.PlotWidget()
layout = pg.GraphicsLayout()
win.setCentralItem(layout)
ax = pg.PlotItem()
layout.addItem(ax)

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 6.28, 30)
y = x[:]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx) + np.cos(yy)

# Add data
ax.setXRange(x.min(), x.max())
ax.setYRange(y.min(), y.max())
c = pg.IsocurveItem(data=z, level=0.5, pen='r')
# c.setParentItem(ax)  # This doesn't work
ax.addItem(c)

# Finish up
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

Or, without the setXRange and setYRange part, it looks like this:

[image]

I want the drawing from the second plot to be stretched to fit on the axes of the first one.
So, I think I just need to tell IsocurveItem how to squeeze and align itself given X, Y, Z data instead of just Z. How can I do that?

P.S. The equivalent* matplotlib contour call would be `contour(x, y, z, levels=[0.5], colors='r')`.

*Have to deal with axis order / row-major vs. col-major; no big deal.

## Failed solutions

### Invisible scaled ImageItem

Add an `ImageItem` and scale it, then make it invisible later. Try to make the `IsocurveItem` scale as well by setting its parent to the `ImageItem`:

```
img = pg.ImageItem(z, axisOrder='row-major')
img.scale((x.max() - x.min()) / img.width(), (y.max() - y.min()) / img.height())
ax.addItem(img)
c.setParentItem(img)
```

The `ImageItem` scales, but the `IsocurveItem` doesn't come along for the ride.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsocurveItem` inherited `.scale()` and `.translate()` methods through `GraphicsObject`, of which it is a subclass. So, just add these lines to the example after defining `c`:

```
c.translate(x.min(), y.min())
c.scale((x.max() - x.min()) / np.shape(z)[0], (y.max() - y.min()) / np.shape(z)[1])
```

To make the test more rigorous, I also changed `x` so it doesn't start at 0:

```
x = np.linspace(10, 16.28, 30)
```

The output is now
[image]

It may be a little easier to visualize with an `ImageItem` in the mix (also translated and scaled):
[image]